# stored procedure wrong in profiler

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a program with an objectdatasource and a gridview.  My Update method looks as if it's passing through the program correctly.  But when it gets to the DB, there's some syntax error.

Here's the stored proc

```
USE [starch]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Starch_Update_KPCodes]    Script Date:       09/13/2011 11:02:1 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[Stored_proc_name]
(
@bookcode as varchar(15),
@PC as varchar(10),
@EReader as varchar(10),
@Tablet as varchar(10),
@Mobile as varchar(10)
)
AS
Begin
Update storedproc
SET 
    Valid_Ans_Nbr = @PC 
where 
    kp_Column=82 and BookCode = @bookcode 
Update 
    Valid_Answers
SET
    Valid_Ans_Nbr = @EReader 
where 
    kp_Column=83 and BookCode = @bookcode


Update
    Valid_Answers
SET 
    Valid_Ans_Nbr = @Tablet 
where 
    kp_Column=84 and BookCode = @bookcode

Update
    alid_Answers
Set
    Valid_Ans_Nbr = @Mobile 
where 
    kp_Column=85 and BookCode = @bookcode

END
```

And then here's what's passed to the database in SQL profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'Starch_Update_KPCodes',
                   N'@bookcode nvarchar(8),
                   @PC nvarchar(1),
                   @EReader nvarchar(1),
                   @Tablet nvarchar(1),
                   @Mobile nvarchar(1)',
                   @bookcode=N'A0027232',
                   @PC=N'1',
                   @EReader=N'1',
                   @Tablet=N'1',
                   @Mobile=N'1'
```

Part of what I think is going on is that I've dropped and recreated the stored procedure a few times.  And this line

```
N'@bookcode nvarchar(8),@PC nvarchar(1),@EReader nvarchar(1),
     @Tablet nvarchar(1),@Mobile nvarchar(1)'
```

probably pertains to some cached version of the stored proc.

I've checked my objectdatasource's updating event to make sure it has the right paramaters.

How can I get rid of that extra text that is being passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: in SSMS, its Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Starch_Update_KPCodes, Line 0
Procedure or function 'Starch_Update_KPCodes' expects parameter '@bookcode', which was not supplied.

Comment: Do you have the correct command type? Stored Procedure vs Text

Comment: yea the @bookcode nvarchar(8), where could that be coming from?

Comment: hey Martin, I think that was it. I didn't declare my command type.  I'll mark as answer if you put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably need to set the command type to stored procedure.

Your existing code will just try and execute the bare statement `Starch_Update_KPCodes` and the parameters you pass in are unused anywhere in that statement.

To do this via `sp_executesql` the statement would need to be

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC Starch_Update_KPCodes 
                             @bookcode=@bookcode, 
                             @PC=@PC, 
                             @EReader=@EReader, 
                             @Tablet=@Tablet, 
                             @Mobile=@Mobile',
                   N'@bookcode nvarchar(8),
                   @PC nvarchar(1),
                   @EReader nvarchar(1),
                   @Tablet nvarchar(1),
                   @Mobile nvarchar(1)',
                   @bookcode=N'A0027232',
                   @PC=N'1',
                   @EReader=N'1',
                   @Tablet=N'1',
                   @Mobile=N'1'
```

Which would be a bit silly compared to just calling the stored proc directly!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand what your problem really is but....

This part defines the parameters to `sp_executesql`.

```
               N'@bookcode nvarchar(8),
               @PC nvarchar(1),
               @EReader nvarchar(1),
               @Tablet nvarchar(1),
               @Mobile nvarchar(1)',
```

And this assigns values to the parameters.

```
               @bookcode=N'A0027232',
               @PC=N'1',
               @EReader=N'1',
               @Tablet=N'1',
               @Mobile=N'1'
```

There is no *extra text* in there as far as I can see.